# Azure Media Services v3: Specify Album Art/Thumbnail for Audio

Tags: azure-media-services

I've looked through the documentation several times, and the only clear discussion is generating thumbnails for a video for scrubbing the time slider for a player.

Is there a way to specify a file (not generate - we have artists generate the specific source image) on the input asset or transform job to set the album art so native players and OS-interop media players would pick it up and show the artwork in their UI?

This is aac audio only.